# Removing duplicates python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with some duplicates that I need to remove. In the dataframe below, where the month, year and type are all the same it should keep the row with the highest sale. Eg:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 1, 7, 10],
                   'year': [2012, 2012, 2013, 2014],
                  'type':['C','C','S','C'],
                  'sale': [55, 40, 84, 31]})
```

After removing duplicates and keeping the highest value of column 'sale' should look like:

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 7, 10],
                   'year': [2012, 2013, 2014],
                  'type':['C','S','C'],
                  'sale': [55, 84, 31]})
```

Comment: df.drop_duplicates(subset= ['month', 'year', 'type'], keep= 'first')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
(df.sort_values('sale',ascending=False)
   .drop_duplicates(['month','year','type']).sort_index())
```

---

```
   month  year type  sale
0      1  2012    C    55
2      7  2013    S    84
3     10  2014    C    31
```

Answer (score 1):

You could groupby and take the max of `sale`:

```
df.groupby(['month', 'year', 'type']).max().reset_index()
    month   year    type    sale
0      1    2012      C      55
1      7    2013      S      84
2      10   2014      C      31
```

If you have another column, like `other`, than you must specify which column to take the `max`, in this way:

```
df.groupby(['month', 'year', 'type'])[['sale']].max().reset_index()
    month   year    type    sale
0      1    2012      C      55
1      7    2013      S      84
2      10   2014      C      31
```